# При попытке передать бинарный файл отдельными кусками(например по 1000 байт) wifi модуль зависает. В чём может быть причина?

Tags: wifi, uart, at

Модуль esp-01s. TCP-соединение, передача кусков происходит с задержкой в 0.5 сек. Передаётся бинарный исполняемый файл, режим AT+CIPMODE=1, соответственно. Программа ожидает чтения и по идее читает, но в какой-то момент происходит зависание, и модуль либо с самого старта перестаёт отвечать, либо через несколько таких передач. Итак, в чём же может быть дело? Может быть настройка не та? Или команды не те? Или же?

Comment: напиши ей нормальную прошивку и не мучай себя передачей)

Comment: Нет. Программа пишется не для WiFi модуля. Он тут всего лишь как дополнительное устройство.

Comment: тот же ответ. ) на espino накатай wifi-serial/spi